# Draw a circle on empty canvas in R magick

Tags: r, imagemagick

I want to create an empty (white) canvas at a certain size (1920×1080). On that canvas, I want to place a filled circle at specific coordinates (e.g., 480, 123).

Even going through the vignette (https://docs.ropensci.org/magick/articles/intro.html), I am not able to create such an image.

The answer needs to work in R.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```r
library(magick)
img <- image_blank(width = 1920, height = 1080, color = "none")
drawing <- image_draw(img)
symbols(480, 123, circles = 5, bg = 'black', inches = FALSE, add = TRUE)
dev.off()
# displaying
# print(drawing)
# saving
image_write(drawing, "img.png")
```